# A estimate in Stability of semiclassical bound states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations with potentials

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Picture below is from the 20th page of 
*Oh, Yong-Geun*, [**Stability of semiclassical bound states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations with potentials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01218621), Commun. Math. Phys. 121, No. 1, 11-33 (1989). [ZBL0693.35132](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0693.35132).

First, how to put off the cut-off function $\chi_h$ in the first red ?

Besides, I can't understand why $\int V''(hy)\chi _h^2(y)u_0^2(y)dy$ is smooth at $h=0$ ?

Third, how to get the second red line ?

> [image]

Comment: What do you mean by “put off the cut-off”?

Comment: @JackyChong  I mean why the cut-off function vanish.